# Trying to post data from an angular html page to a php page for processing and email

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, contact-form

I've been working with angular for a short time and I'm trying to get a contact form to submit to a php file at the domain route that's set up to mail us.

I've gotten the php to mail us but none of the date is being carried over from the angular application.

Here's my code:

```js
angular.module('demoapp')
  .controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache) {

  var method = 'POST';
  var url = 'contact.php';
  $scope.codeStatus = '';
  $scope.add = function() {
    $http({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      data: $.param({'data' : FormData}),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      cache: $templateCache
    }).
    success(function(response) {
        $scope.codeStatus = response.data;
    }).
    error(function(response) {
        $scope.codeStatus = response || 'Request failed';
    });
    return false;
  };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contact-form-wrapper">
  <h2>Write Us</h2>
  <form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <input class="formtop" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name (required)">
    <input class="formtop" type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email (required)">
    <input class="formlong" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" size="50">
    <textarea class="formarea" name="message" placeholder="Message" size="50"></textarea>
    <input class="submit-link" type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

It's posting to this php file:

```
<?php

$Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Email = $_POST['mail'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
$time = date ("h:i A");
$to = "dummy@email.com";
$subject = $Subject;
$msg="
Name: $Name
Email: $Email
Subject: $Subject
Message: $Message
Submitted on: $date $time
IP Address: $ip_address
Host Name: $hostname \n
";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: website@traffikonline.com");
?>
```

It's probably something very minor that I'm missing, but I've checked a lot of places for answers and this is the closest I've gotten. Grunt and inspector isn't tossing any errors about the jscript and the php file DOES email me (just no data).

Thanks!

Comment: I've had this a bunch. Using the $_POST variable doesn't work. Has to do with how angular posts the data. Try file_get_contents('php://input'). You may need to json_decode after that.

Comment: I'm pretty unfamiliar with json, unfortunately. Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your php to :

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data);
$Subject = $json->subject;
$Name = $json->name;
$Email = $json->mail;
$Message = $json->message;
```

Comment: I was able to fix the form by using $_GET instead in my php code, but i'm very curious about your method. I updated my PHP with your code and tried both with method="post" and without method="post" and was unable to grab the data. Was there anything more to it? :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question because I'm currently working on my own Angular + PHP contact form.  Something glaring in your code to me is the total lack of ng declarations.

Where is ng-app, ng-controller and ng-model in your html?  You won't be able to get the data if there's no data binding going on. Also, instead of a form action, you should call the "add" function defined in your controller using ng-submit.

```
<div ng-app="demoapp" class="contact-form-wrapper">
  <h2>Write Us</h2>
  <form name="form" ng-controller="ContactCtrl" ng-submit="form.$valid && add()" method="post" enctype="text/plain" novalidate>
    <input class="formtop" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name (required)" ng-model="input.name" required>
    <input class="formtop" ng-model="input.email" type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email (required)" required>
    <input class="formlong" ng-model="input.subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" size="50">
    <textarea class="formarea" ng-model="input.msg" name="message" placeholder="Message" size="50" required></textarea>
    <input class="submit-link" type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

As for the PHP stuff, I'm not really sure.  But your Angular code is definitely messed up.